# Add unread notification to wpf microsoft ribbonbutton image

Tags: wpf, ribbon-control

I want to ask the same question as [Coxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343293/icon-badge-overlay-for-notifications-in-silverlight-xaml): I want to show number of unread items on top of the image of an *RibbonButton*.

Example:

[image: Like this]

Can I do it without modifying a copy of the entire template? The reason that I am asking the same question again is that I am using the Microsoft Ribbon control and the solution given from Coxy question, can only be applied to the Ribbon control from Telerik.

Comment: Have you looked at using an Adorner? http://djfr.wordpress.com/2012/03/30/creating-a-notification-button-in-wpf/

Comment: *I want to ask the same question as Coxy*... why? We don't like duplicate questions on this website... what makes this one different enough to not be closed as a duplicate? I don't see any reason why you can't follow the answer from the other question.

Comment: Coxy is using a ribbon from telerik and you can not apply the same solution to the Microsoft ribbon. And Sheridan next time try to be polite.

Comment: Martin, why do you think this only works with the Teleric Ribbon Button? You just have to edit the `ControlTemplate` of your WPF Ribbon Button.

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding this in an answer because it's too long to put in a comment.

I went to the Microsoft Download site & downloaded the Ribbon control's source from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11877).  The complete template with all of the triggers are in there.  I won't paste any of it in here as it's copyrighted, but anybody can download it and install it.  I think.

The installer installs a zip file with the source in the C:\Program Files (x86)\MicrosoftRibbonForWPF folder.  I extracted the zip file into a VS project folder.

The template I'm looking at is in the v4.0\Themes\Generic.xaml file.

Those bad triggers do indeed reference the same property.  It's the `HighContrast` property of the `SystemParameters2.Current` static object.

You can probably put together a custom template for your application that does not even use those triggers.  At least, that's what I would do.

Answer (score 0):

Martin Andersen is right: it is currently not possible to create a ribbon button in XAML, right-click it in the Document Outline window, select Edit template and create a copy of it. VS will display the following error message and no template is generated:

[image: Visual Studio error occurring when creating a copy of the ribbon button control template]

If you do the same thing in Blend, the same error message occurs, but a control template for the ribbon button will actually be generated. Unfortunately, this template is erroneous. It contains several triggers whose Binding bind to `(0)`. Here is an example of such an erroneous trigger.

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding (0)}" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="OuterBorder" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.MenuTextBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="OuterBorder" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="OuterBorder" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="CornerRadius" TargetName="OuterBorder" Value="0"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

This issue was also reported to Microsoft: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/794891/problems-styling-wpf-4-5-ribbon-control
They provide the default control templates as attachments to this issue but unfortunately I cannot download them. The resulting file is always empty (zero kilobyte). Can anybody of you download it?

**Proposed Solution**

My current advise is to encapsulate the button within another custom control that derives from `ContentControl` and handles all the notification bubble. You then can set the button as the content of this new control. I'm currently working on an example - I will update this post when I find something useful.

**The erroneous control template**

Here is the complete erroneous control template of `RibbonButton`:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="RibbonButtonWithNotificationStyle" TargetType="{x:Type RibbonButton}">
    <Border x:Name="OuterBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
        <Border x:Name="InnerBorder" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
            <StackPanel x:Name="StackPanel">
                <Image x:Name="PART_Image" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Height="32" Margin="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=LargeImageMargin, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type Ribbon}}}" Source="{TemplateBinding LargeImageSource}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="32"/>
                <Grid x:Name="Grid" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <RibbonTwoLineText x:Name="TwoLineText" HorizontalAlignment="Center" LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight" LineHeight="13" Margin="1,1,1,0" TextAlignment="Center" Text="{TemplateBinding Label}" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ControlSizeDefinition.ImageSize, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="Large">
            <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="44"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="66"/>
            <Setter Property="MinHeight" TargetName="Grid" Value="26"/>
            <Setter Property="RibbonTwoLineText.HasTwoLines" TargetName="TwoLineText" Value="True"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ControlSizeDefinition.ImageSize, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="Small">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="22"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="PART_Image" Value="1,0"/>
            <Setter Property="Source" TargetName="PART_Image" Value="{Binding SmallImageSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" TargetName="PART_Image" Value="16"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="PART_Image" Value="16"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" TargetName="TwoLineText" Value="Left"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="TwoLineText" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="Orientation" TargetName="StackPanel" Value="Horizontal"/>
        </DataTrigger>

        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding ControlSizeDefinition.ImageSize, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="Small"/>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsInQuickAccessToolBar, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto"/>
        </MultiDataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ControlSizeDefinition.IsLabelVisible, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="TwoLineText" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ControlSizeDefinition.ImageSize, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="Collapsed">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="PART_Image" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="OuterBorder" Value="{Binding MouseOverBackground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="OuterBorder" Value="{Binding MouseOverBorderBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="InnerBorder" Value="#80FFFFFF"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="OuterBorder" Value="{Binding FocusedBackground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="OuterBorder" Value="{Binding FocusedBorderBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="InnerBorder" Value="#80FFFFFF"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="OuterBorder" Value="{Binding PressedBackground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="OuterBorder" Value="{Binding PressedBorderBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="InnerBorder" Value="Transparent"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsInControlGroup" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="OuterBorder" Value="{Binding Ribbon.BorderBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="OuterBorder" Value="0,0,1,0"/>
            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" TargetName="OuterBorder" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" TargetName="InnerBorder" Value="0"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="PART_Image" Value="0.5"/>
            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="OuterBorder" Value="#FF9E9E9E"/>
        </Trigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding (0)}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="OuterBorder" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.MenuTextBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="OuterBorder" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="OuterBorder" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" TargetName="OuterBorder" Value="0"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Value="True"/>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding (0)}" Value="True"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="OuterBorder" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightBrushKey}}"/>
        </MultiDataTrigger>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Value="True"/>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="False"/>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding (0)}" Value="True"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="OuterBorder" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
        </MultiDataTrigger>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, FallbackValue=false, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Value="True"/>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="False"/>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding (0)}" Value="True"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="OuterBorder" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightBrushKey}}"/>
        </MultiDataTrigger>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True"/>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding (0)}" Value="True"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="OuterBorder" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="OuterBorder" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" TargetName="OuterBorder" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="InnerBorder" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="OuterBorder" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}"/>
        </MultiDataTrigger>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsKeyboardFocused, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True"/>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding (0)}" Value="True"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="OuterBorder" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="OuterBorder" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" TargetName="OuterBorder" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="InnerBorder" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="OuterBorder" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}"/>
        </MultiDataTrigger>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsPressed, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True"/>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding (0)}" Value="True"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="OuterBorder" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="OuterBorder" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" TargetName="OuterBorder" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="OuterBorder" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}"/>
        </MultiDataTrigger>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsInControlGroup, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True"/>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding (0)}" Value="True"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="OuterBorder" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightLightBrushKey}}"/>
        </MultiDataTrigger>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="False"/>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding (0)}" Value="True"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="OuterBorder" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
        </MultiDataTrigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: Is it possible to figure out what the properties the bad bindings are supposed to be bound to?  That is, are there enough clues in the code to give you a hint as to what they should be bound to?

Comment: I couldn't but I didn't take a close look. I've updated the post with the erroneous template.

Comment: There's no real way to know, but I have a gut feeling that all of the {Binding (0)} conditions are on the same property.  It seems like every other property is fine. It might be some property of the control that indicates if a drop down menu is visible or if one is in the control.  I don't know enough about the class to know what the property might be, though.

Comment: Could it be that these are internal properties? This would explain why the control template cannot be resolved properly.

Comment: I suppose its possible that they could be internal properties. The properties have to be visible to the code in the WPF DLLs.  I checked the documentation and the Ribbon controls are all in a separate DLL, so my gut says they're not internal properties, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: Also, I don't seem to have the DLL with the Ribbon controls in it on my workstation.  I have VS 2013 installed, and I would have thought that these controls would be in the VS 2013 package.

Comment: You have to add the System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon DLL. It is not referenced by the default WPF Application project, but it is part of the BCL.